# Mysql : dump database, all tables name are in lowercase on Windows server (not on Linux)

Tags: mysql

From a Linux server I perform a dump of my database.

```
mysqldump -u root -p database_from_linux >database_from_linux.sql
```

And I create the new database on a Windows server from this dump:

```
mysql -u root -p database < database_from_linux.sql
```

On the Windows server, all tables name are in lowercase, whereas in linux server they are in uppercase.

In the SQL script, the tables names are in lower case.

How can i keep the uppercase in the Windows server database?

Server Linux 14.10
Mysql 5.5.40-ubuntu01
Mysql workbench 6.1

Server Windows 2012
Mysql 5.5.47
Mysql workbench 6.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) you can set `lower_case_table_names=0` on linux and `lower_case_table_names=2` on windows. This will preserve case but you also have to specify correct case when writing queries.

I would argue that it's better to set `lower_case_table_names=1` everywhere. You can still type queries using any case but internally it's converted to lowercase.

Comment: I would go for the first option, because I need my tables names to be in lowercase. But the problem is that it tells me that the lower_case_table_names cannot be set to 2 in a Windows server 2012.